# How to protect certain columns in an Excel file from modifications?

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I'm creating an Excel file using C#, but I want some columns to be protected from modification. The problem is that I don't know how many rows I'm going to have in that file. I used the following code:

```
 xlWorkSheet.Cells.Locked = false;
 xlWorkSheet.Range["A1:A3"].Locked = true;
            xlWorkSheet.Range["B1"].Locked = true;
            xlWorkSheet.Range["C1"].Locked = true;
            xlWorkSheet.Range["D1:D3"].Locked = true;
            xlWorkSheet.Range["E1:E3"].Locked = true;
            xlWorkSheet.Range["F1:F3"].Locked = true;
            xlWorkSheet.Protect(misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

I know there is a Range, but I need a universal solution when I don't know how many rows an Excel file has.

Comment: I think this will do the trick: `xlWorkSheet.Range["D:D"].Locked = true;`. I'm not sure, but give it a try.

Comment: Excel Security is like a wall of thin paper :)